# How to change zoom of a WPF control but still taking the full space?

Tags: wpf

In a WPF application, I'm using a web browser control (actually it's awesomium, but I'm not sure this is important). This control is using some kind of interop.

I want my app to be able to "zoom out" the web content. The web content should be reduced to 50% of its size.

If I apply `ScalTransform` only, the browser control is zoom out as exptected (everything is smaller), but the visible bounds of the controls are also reduced.

I want to web control to take the full available place of its container. How to achieve this?

I've done this by now:

```
<Canvas SizeChanged="Canvas_SizeChanged"
        MinWidth="100"
        MinHeight="100">
    <Custom:WebControl x:Name="browser"
                       RenderTransformOrigin="0,0"
                       Width="100"
                       Height="100">
        <Custom:WebControl.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5"
                                ScaleY="0.5" />
                <SkewTransform />
                <RotateTransform />
                <TranslateTransform />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Custom:WebControl.RenderTransform>           
    </Custom:WebControl>
</Canvas>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void Canvas_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    browser.Width = e.NewSize.Width * 2;
    browser.Height = e.NewSize.Height * 2;
}
```

This is working, a bit inefficient. I'm wondering if there is better place to do this (pure XML?).

Comment: you perform the ScaleTransform on the Webbrowser control itself, which obviously makes the whole webbrowse control small. you want to resize just its content. as Awesomium as well as the inbuilt webbrowser isnt pure wpf, you have to check whether the control itself supports something like this.

Comment: @JoachimKerschbaumer: I have this case now for webbrower control, but isn't there a generic method, applicable to any UIElement?

Comment: well, you can apply a scale transform to any FrameworkElement, but this changes the frameworkelement as such. if you just want it´s content to be scaled, a content control has to take care of this. however, this might be nearly impossible in your case as there is some interop going (no pure wpf)

Comment: are you suggesting me to add a new level of container (a grid) and play with the container ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies to version 1.7 RC3 (available [here](http://awesomium.com/download/)).

- The Awesomium.NET WPF `WebControl` is actually pure WPF (when `ViewType` is set to `Offscreen`, which is the default value).
- Check an example of what you're trying to do, [here](http://forums.awesomium.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=110&p=199&hilit=Zoom#p199).